# size_t used as a value in a formula

Tags: c, size-t

Here is a short snippet of a function reading lines. 
How is that possible that it compares `bufsize` with `((size_t)-1)/2` ?

I imagined comparing a variable to eg. `int` - that is just impossible; to INT_MAX on the contrary it is correct, I think.
So how can that code actually work and give no errors?

```
int c;
size_t bufsize = 0;
size_t size = 0;

while((c=fgetc(infile)) != EOF) {
    if (size >= bufsize) {
        if (bufsize == 0)
                bufsize = 2;
        else if (bufsize <= ((size_t)-1)/2)
                bufsize = 2*size;
        else {
                free(line);
                exit(3);
        }
        newbuf = realloc(line,bufsize);
        if (!newbuf) {
                free(line);
                abort();
        }
        line = newbuf;
    }
    /* some other operations */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code relies on some assumptions about bits and then does a well known hack for finding the maximum size_t value (provided that size_t doesn't accommodate more bits than the register, a safe bet on many machines).

First it fills a register up with `1` bits, then it *casts* it into a `size_t` data type, so the comparison will work.  As long as that register is larger in number of bits than the `size_t` data type, then the (if any) unused `1` bits will be truncated, and you will get the largest unsigned number that can fit in `size_t` bits.

After you have that, it divides by two to get half of that number, and does the comparison to see if it *seems* to be safe to increase size without going over the "maximum" `size_t`.  but by then, it's dividing a `size_t` data type, and comparing two `size_t` data types (a type safe operation).

If you really wanted to remove this bit-wizardy (ok, it's not the worst example of bit wizardy I've seen).  Consider that the following snippet

```
    else if (bufsize <= ((size_t)-1)/2)
            bufsize = 2*size;
```

could be replaced with

```
    else if (bufsize <= (MAX_SIZE/2)
            bufsize = 2*size;
```

and be type safe *without casting* and more readable.

Comment: The macro exists and its name is `SIZE_MAX`

Comment: Awesome.  At one point in time the `(size_t)-1` hack seemed to be the only game in town.  Perhaps it's just knowing to much about the bits under the covers that kept me from finding it.  I'll update the answer

Comment: `(size_t) -1` is still used explicitly in the Standard when they want to reserve a `size_t` value to indicate an error. For example *(C99, 7.24.6.3.1p3) The mbrlen function returns a value between zero and n, inclusive, (size_t)(-2), or (size_t)(-1).*

Comment: @ouah "and n, inclusive, (size_t)(-2), or (size_t)(-1)" What would be the difference between casting `-2` and `-1` ?

Comment: @PeterKowalski there is no difference between `SIZE_MAX` and `(size_t)(-1)`, and between `(SIZE_MAX - 1)` and `(size_t)(-2)`

Comment: This is a much misleading answer. There is nothing to know about the "bits" and this is not a "hack". Unsigned arithmetic in C is defined through values and `-1` converted to an unsigned type will always be the maximal value of that type minus one.

Comment: @JensGustedt everybody says here that that conversion gives maximal value (not with `1` subtracted)    Which is correct?

Comment: @JensGustedt I think people are confusing two different things.  ouah never said that the largest size had to be `(size_t)(-2)`.  He said it had to either be `(size_t)(-2)` or `(size_t)(-1)`.  With such a definition, you _really_ want to use `SIZE_MAX`, just in case you're on the odd platform where it happens to be `(size_t)(-2)`.  My platform SIZE_MAX = 18446744073709551615UL =  `(size_t)-1`.  Someone else's might be the same, or might be `(size_t)-2`, that possibility alone _is a very good reason_ to use `SIZE_MAX`.

Answer (score 6):

```
(size_t)-1
```

This is *casting* the value `-1` to a `size_t`. `(type)value` is a cast in C.

Since `size_t` is an unsigned type, this is actually the maximum value that `size_t` can hold, so it's used to make sure that the buffer size can actually be safely doubled (hence the subsequent division by two).

Comment: You could add that -1 is all Bits set to one because of Two-Complement representation and therefore the maximum value.

Comment: @halex, this has nothing to do with the representation of the number. `int` (and thus `-1`) could well be represented in one of the two other possible representations that would still lead to the same result. Conversion from signed to unsigned types just uses the value and not the representation.

Comment: @JensGustedt The goal of (size_t)-1 is to get the maximum value of the type size_t, and that is all bits set to one. If I understand it correctly then if -1 would be represented in an other representation than 2-Complement it were not all 1s.

Comment: @halex: You're wrong; it has nothing to do with the representation because casts do not operate on representations; they operate on values. `(size_t)-1` reduces the integer -1 modulo `SIZE_MAX+1` to a value in the range 0 to `SIZE_MAX`. `(size_t)-1` is just a way of writing `SIZE_MAX` without depending on the macro (which did not exist prior to C99).

Comment: @R.. Ah ok thank you. I always thought that the same bitpattern is interpreted as the new value, but it's value based. I searched in the standard too and found in 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers: `Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.` That explains everything :).

Answer (score 2):

`(size_t)-1` casts `-1` to the type `size_t`, which results in `SIZE_MAX` (a macro defined in *stdint.h*), the maximum value that the `size_t` type can hold.

So the comparison is checking whether `bufsize` is less than or equal to one half the maximum value that can be contained in a `size_t`

Answer (score 0):

The `size_t` in `((size_t)-1)/2)` is simply being used as a cast: casting `-1` to `size_t`.

The *trick* here is that `size_t` is unsigned, so the cast `(size_t) -1` will be converted to the maximum value of `size_t`, or `SIZE_MAX`. This is useful in the context of the loop. However, I'd prefer to see `SIZE_MAX` used *directly* rather than this trick.

Comment: `SIZE_MAX` was not defined prior to C99, so code aiming for maximum portability will use `(size_t)-1` to get the max value of `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

size_t isn't being interpreted as a value, it's being used to cast the value of negative one to the type size_t.

```
((size_t)-1)/2
```

is casting -1 to a size_t and then dividing by 2.